# How object-to-object communication in Java works?

Tags: java, oop, methods

I am new in learning Java just finished with Methods lecture. I am working on assignment and I need to write program for Money transfer service. I have two classes, first one is CurrencyConverter and second one is MoneyTransferService, which uses the functionality of CurrencyConverter class. In the MoneyTransferService class I have main method where I created a MoneyTransferService object, which in turn is using the services offered by CurrentConverter object. I dont understand how object are communicate between each other?

When I run program with commented code works perfectly, but I dont undrestand why I have to create an object which will use service offered by another object?

```java
class MoneyTransferService {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
                CurrencyConverter cc = new CurrencyConverter(); 

                /*double amount = cc.computeTransferAmount(0, 1000);                
               
                double fee = cc.computeTransferFee(0, 1000);
                
                System.out.println("Transfer Amount: " + amount);

                System.out.println("Transfer Fee: " + fee);*/
                
                

                
                MoneyTransferService transferService = new MoneyTransferService();
                
                

                double transferAmount = transferService.computeTransferAmount(0, 1000);

                double transferFee = transferService.computeTransferFee(0, 1000);

                System.out.println("Transfer Amount: " + transferAmount);

                System.out.println("Transfer Fee: " + transferFee);
                
                
    }  
   
}
```

```java
public class CurrencyConverter {   

        // Currency exchange rates of different currencies relative to 1 US dollar

       double[] exchangeRates = new double[] {63.0, 3.0, 3.0, 595.5, 18.0, 107.0, 2.0};

   

       void setExchangeRates(double[] rates) {

             exchangeRates = rates;

        }

        void updateExchangeRate(int countryIndex, double newVal) {

             exchangeRates[countryIndex] = newVal;

        }



        double getExchangeRate(int countryIndex) {

            return exchangeRates[countryIndex];

        }

        double computeTransferAmount(int countryIndex, double amount) {

            return amount * getExchangeRate(countryIndex);

        }
        
        double computeTransferFee (int countryIndex, double amount) {
            
            return computeTransferAmount(countryIndex, amount) * 0.02;
            
        }

   

        void printCurrencies() {

             System.out.println("\nrupee: " + exchangeRates[0]);

             System.out.println("dirham: " + exchangeRates[1]);

             System.out.println("real: " + exchangeRates[2]);

             System.out.println("chilean_peso: " + exchangeRates[3]);

             System.out.println("mexican_peso: " + exchangeRates[4]);

             System.out.println("_yen: " + exchangeRates[5]);

             System.out.println("$australian: " + exchangeRates[exchangeRates.length-1]);

       }

}
```

Comment: Why would you "have to create an object which will use service offered by another object" - because the service can do something you need done. This divides up the work in an organized way, either physically with services that are running as separate processes / modules / nodes / whatever - or at least conceptually with different classes handling different aspects of the application.

Comment: Hi @topsail, thanks for explaining. Also I want to ask how am I going to connect them so they can communicate between each other in the main method? Because when I run program I am getting this message :

Comment: MoneyTransferService.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
                double transferAmount = transferService.computeTransferAmount(0, 1000);
                                                       ^
  symbol:   method computeTransferAmount(int,int)
  location: variable transferService of type MoneyTransferService
MoneyTransferService.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
                double transferFee = transferService.computeTransferFee(0, 1000);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the *transferService* instance to access the *computeTransferAmount*, and *computeTransferFee*, methods.
These methods are defined within the *CurrencyConverter* class, which can be referenced via the *cc* instance you've created.

```java
double transferAmount = cc.computeTransferAmount(0, 1000);
double transferFee = cc.computeTransferFee(0, 1000);
```

Comment: I submitted assignment, but I got answer that I had to create object CurrencyConverter and two methods inside MonyTransferService class CurrencyConverter cc = new CurrencyConverter();
        double computeTransferAmount(int countryIndex, double amount) {
                return cc.computeTransferAmount(countryIndex, amount);  
        }
        double computeTransferFee(int countryIndex, double amount) {
                double transferAmount = computeTransferAmount(countryIndex, amount);
                double transferFee = transferAmount * 0.02;
                return transferFee;
  }